# .NET Random Slow Site Load Time

Tags: .net, performance, precompiled

I have a .NET application running on an IIS7 server. A service provider has a polling utility that pings the server every hour to ensure it is running properly. Sporadically, maybe 3-4 times a day, the response is lagging past the threshold they have set of 3 seconds.

The .NET application is pre-compiled and running in release mode. The page that is being pinged does not connect to a database and for the most part just displays static HTML (the only .net code used is a few include statements within the Master template).

I am at a loss of why it could still be loading slowly. I've set the Application Pool idle to not timeout for 70 minutes which would prevent the recycling from occurring when the poller hits, but that still hasn't resolved the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up some logging in each method of the page that's being request and record timestamps.  Logging in Global.asax.cs may also be telling.  That's probably the quickest an easiest way to try and narrow down the culprit.

Comment: Application_Start and Application_End would be good events to log in Global.asax.cs to see if the application is shutting down after an idle period.